# Caught cheating

Tags: cheating

I'm 2 weeks away from being done with my program. A classmate & myself got caught looking at the quiz answers while the teacher left the room, but all of our 10 other classmates were benefiting from the answers also. Technically they were cheating also because they didn't go tell the instructor. We both got a 0 on our quiz. We go to a private college. Their policy says either suspension, warning or expulsion. I don't know what to do. My director told me I wouldn't get expulsion & she met with the school education director yesterday to make a decision, but was never told anything. Can they possibly kick me out with 2 weeks left of my program? What about the other 10 girls who were getting the answers? Shouldn't they technically be cheaters also because if the teacher wouldn't had walked in they would had the answers. Help!! I'm slowly dying. I own up I was wrong for doing what I did. I apologize to my instructor & director because that's not the type of student I am at all. I don't know what made me do what I did, but I happen & I know I am an adult.

Comment: You are an adult and you face the consequences of your actions. The consequences depend on your college regulations. What kind of help you want from us?

Comment: RE: _Shouldn't they technically be cheaters also because if the teacher wouldn't had walked in they would had the answers?_ This sounds like you are trying to shift the blame, which to me is the most disturbing part of this question. You did something ethically wrong; **own it**.

Comment: I'm not trying to shift no blame. I have told all my instructors that I know what I did was wrong, I take full responsibility for what I did.

Comment: Please use this waiting time to do as many good deeds for everyone around you as possible.  Use this anxious time productively.

Comment: _"What about the other 10 girls who were getting the answers? Shouldn't they technically be cheaters also? I know it's none of my business, but they were cheaters also. All of them had the answers."_ That's not owning it; that's time-sharing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably won't get suspended without a warning. Please learn a lesson and don't do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on how important this test was. You say 'quiz': is it an informal test, a larger assessment, an exam? On the one hand your teacher should not have left the room [I have known this to happen before in university exams too] but you should also not have succumbed to temptation. You say other student 'benefited' from the answers? What does this mean - they didn't look at the answers themselves but they asked questions to those that did? A lot here is not clear.

It's completely down to a] the importance of the 'quiz' and b] your college. I would not expect them to suspend/expel you for a short test or assessment, but a major exam, maybe. Really I don't think anyone can give you a definitive answer, since it's so relative to your college. But at least going forward you'll know not to do this kind of thing again.

Comment: It wasn't a big exam. It was a short 10 multiple quiz based on a reading. We were reading off the answers to the whole class so everyone had the answers to the quiz, but my classmate & I were the ones caught looking at the quiz.

Comment: For something like that it's extremely unlikely that you'll get anything more than a warning. Just learn from it and don't repeat it.

Comment: Oh trust me I have learned from it! First & last time I do that! My career it's way more important & I'm two weeks away from graduating. I just hate that they're making me wait so long to give me an answers because this happened Wednesday. I don't go back to school until Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Usually they let you off with a warning if you are caught. However, it depends on the level of examination you are appearing for. It's good that you apologised for your mistake and have realised not to go for it again.

Comment: What do you mean let you off without a warning? We already received a 0 on our quiz. My instructors & director said they told the education director the type of student I was & that they put in a good word for me

Comment: You can't expect them to actually grade your exam, can you? I think you faced resonable consequences here.

Comment: The zero marks is a statement of how good your knowledge of the exam material is evidenced to be. Since you looked up the answers, there is no evidence that you know anything. So, I wouldn't consider the 0 the penalty per se, but rather a side effect of your action. Other penalties, cautioning, warning, mark on transcripts etc. may be possible, but if this is your first ever offence, you may get away with a warning, (and the lost opportunity to get marks), depending on department.

Comment: Well we got a 0 before taking the quiz, but my instructor still made us take the quiz with the rest of the class. Let me state this that this instructor always showed us the answer to previous quizzes then left the room. I never before went up there to get the answers, but one girl time after time did. My department is dental hygiene

Comment: What kind of instructor leaves the room during a quiz with the answers at the desk?

Answer (score 0):

I'll address something the others haven't addressed yet.

> What about the other 10 girls who were getting the answers?

It is absolutely none of your business what happens to the others in the class and not your judgement call to make. Forget about them and focus on yourself. Learn from your mistake and never let it happen again.

Comment: I know it's none of my business, but they were cheaters also. All of them had the answers.